# How can I get a ```<td>``` tag without text value occupy a position in a list in Selenium Python when getting table HTML data?

Tags: python, selenium

I need get HTML table data as lists. The table has 100 columns and 50 rows. Not every `<td>` has text value and each row is different from others (the no text value in different columns)

So when I using `row.text`, it returns a list ignoring the one has no text. each row's list has different length. This is not good for writing the list in excel file.

If I do it one `<td>` by one `<td>` to form a list. This is too slow.

```py
for row in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="mytable"]/tbody/tr')
    print(row.text)
```

html

```html
<table id='mytable'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href='javascript:...'>cbd</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ttt</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Using BeautifulSoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautitulSoup(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="mytable"]/tbody').get_attribute('innerHTML'), features='lxml')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    list = ([text for text in tr.strings])
    print(list)
```

I still get a list like ['abc','cbd'], i need get a list as ['abc', '', 'cbd']

Comment: Can you show us the code that is taking longer time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Selenium to grab the whole table, then use Beautiful Soup to parse it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="mytable"]')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_table)

# This is a fast way to get a list of all the <td> tags, even the empty ones:
td_list = soup('td')
```

And then from there you can write the td tags to your excel file.

But depending on your situation, I would probably just use the requests library instead of selenium to get the HTML for the whole page, then use Beautiful Soup to get just the table, then parse the td tags from there.

Comment: Actually, I need write text to excel file, not the td tags. I tried ```tr.get_text('|')```, but still not including the one without text.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer! I know it wasn't directly the code you needed to fix your specific problem, but you said it got you on the right path.

Comment: You can also try something like this: ```for row in soup('tr'): for tag in row('td'): list.append(tag.text)``` which does give you the blank one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gbergeson. I finnaly get the way using beautifulsoup not skipping the null text.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautitulSoup(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="mytable"]/tbody').get_attribute('innerHTML'), features='lxml')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    l = (td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td'))
    print(l)
```